Why use DI frameworks such as Koin and Hilt in Android Application?
Kotlin provides syntax sugar for the singleton pattern. Can't we use it to initialize a Service or a tool class?
I have just switched from backend development to Android development. Is the use of DI framework in Android development related to memory leaks? I hope to have an answer.

Opinion based questions like this aren't allowed on stack overflow.  It's a better fit on the software engineering stack exchange.

In addition, this is a topic that has been widely discussed. See the documentation and the many, many results for searching on phrases like android reasons for dependency injection in major Internet search engines.

Using a DI framework is beneficial when your dependencies need to scale across multiple or future components. It can also simplify managing instances of those dependencies.
However, a framework isn’t required to implement DI. Frameworks are useful tools for organizing larger, more complex dependencies, but for simpler cases where a dependency is only used a few times, building modules and components might be unnecessary.
The key consideration is reusability and complexity. If you have a complicated set of dependencies that would benefit from being modularized and reused, a framework can help. If not, manual DI works fine. It’s important to understand the tool and decide if it will save you time and effort.
Even when using a framework, you don’t have to rely on it for everything. You can still create simple instances manually and use the framework for handling more complex dependencies.
